# ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-date-functions

Need assistance on Converting a Military to Standard Time.

I have the code below: However, it gives me error ORA-01850

```
select to_char (to_date(tst_time, 'HH24MI'), 'HH:MI AM')  integer_time  FROM STATUS_HISTORY
where tst_id = '75344'
```

I'm thinking that its because the value on tst_time only has 3 characters for the first 2 entry. How can I add 0 on the beginning of the tst_time if it contains only 3 numbers?

```
Table Value   Expected Result
 
TST_Time  integer_time

958      09:58 AM     
541      05:41 AM
1609     04:09 PM
```

Comment: Removed the Microsoft SQL Server tag since it does not apply to your question. Specify only relevant tags as detailed in each tag description.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you can use `lpad()`:

```
select  to_char(to_date(lpad(tst_time, 4, '0'), 'HH24MI'), 'HH:MI AM') integer_time
from (select '1609' as tst_time from dual union all
      select '948' from dual
     )
```

This adds a zero in front when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `tst_time` is a number - which seems likely; if it was a string it would make sense for it to already have the leading zero - then you are doing an implicit conversion to a string with the `to_date()` call.

If you make that an explicit conversion then you can introduce the leading zero(s) at that point:

```
to_char(to_date(to_char(tst_time, 'FM0000'), 'HH24MI'), 'HH:MI AM')
```

The `to_char(tst_time, 'FM0000')` converts 958 to 0958. (The FM part stops it having a leading space to allow for a +/- sign; doesn't really matter here though.)

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f45bf95ccce542aa22ced88defcc410d)